# Cannot Click On Screencast When Debugging WebView Via chrome://inspect

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug a webview in an Android app using `chrome://inspect`. Everything works fine except that clicking on the screencast has no effect. Device OS is Android 6 and I am using Windows 10.

Any ideas on what can be the problem?